# Invoking Camel restlet producer giving an exception

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am working on a sample application to invoke a RESTful web service using camel routing. And the REST service is secured. I coded like this

```
from("file:data/source?noop=true")
                        .process(new Processor() {                          
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
                                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");
                                exchange.getIn().setHeader(RestletConstants.RESTLET_LOGIN, "xxxx");
                                exchange.getIn().setHeader(RestletConstants.RESTLET_PASSWORD, "xxxx");
                            }
                        })
                        .to("restlet:http://xxxx/xxxx/batch/query-by-hwid.xml");
```

I am just picking xml file in from endpoint which is input or body to the REST service. And before passing this xml to the REST service, am setting up the headers for security. But am not able to hit the service and it is giving me an exception saying

```
org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking http://xxxx/xxxxx/batch/query-by-hwid.xml with statusCode: 405 /n responseBody:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Draft//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 405--Method Not Allowed</TITLE>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="WebLogic Server">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white">
<FONT FACE=Helvetica><BR CLEAR=all>
<TABLE border=0 cellspacing=5><TR><TD><BR CLEAR=all>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica" COLOR="black" SIZE="3"><H2>Error 405--Method Not Allowed</H2>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE border=0 width=100% cellpadding=10><TR><TD VALIGN=top WIDTH=100% BGCOLOR=white><FONT FACE="Courier New"><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H3>From RFC 2068 <i>Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1</i>:</H3>
</FONT><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H4>10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed</H4>
</FONT><P><FONT FACE="Courier New">The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.</FONT></P>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I will be thankful if you can shed some light on this. Thank you.
I am using Camel Version : 2.13.

Answer (score 0):

Rest services usually requires and use the Accept header.

So you should set this header

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
```

Comment: Thank you Claus. But i am getting same exception after adding the mentioned header.

Comment: "The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource." Claus, what does this exceptions has to say ...